# Перевод punycode в кириллицу

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть база данных, в нескольких столбцах которой есть текст (домен) в формате punycode. Он передается через json, и записывается в бд.

Вывожу в таблицу значения, которые мне нужны, все ок. Но вот возникла необходимость выводить не punycode, а кириллицу. Вывожу так:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT first_referrer, last_referrer, current_url FROM `data` WHERE GA=?");

foreach ($res_array as $row){
    echo "<td>" . $row["first_referrer"] . "<br>" . $row["last_referrer"] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["current_url"] . "</td>";}
```

На выходе такая таблица [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.idn-to-utf8.php ?

Comment: Не работает, либо я юзаю не так: echo "<td>" . idn_to_utf8('$row["current_url"]') . "</td>";

Comment: что на входе, что на выходе получается? конкретный пример приведите

Comment: вот прям в таком написании у вас вообще ошибка парсинга будет ибо кавычки лишние

Comment: т.е вот так echo "<td>" . idn_to_utf8($row["current_url"]) . "</td>"; должно работать? А не работает, таблица ломается

Comment: из вас клещами все тащить надо? ) что значит таблица ломается? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$url = $row["current_url"];
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$url = str_replace($host, idn_to_utf8($host), $url);

echo "<td>" . $url . "</td>";
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]